# How do I fix my USB drive to get its original 32GB size back that not showing unallocated partition in manage?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, partitioning, usb-flash-drive

I have a 32GB flash disk that only shows 8MB of it. I tested methods like "disk part commend", "check management", using best tools like BOOTICE and many others, but that only can show just 8MB!

I need a way to fully restore the hidden portion to bring back all 32GB.

This is the view of BOOTICE that only shows 8mb:

[image: this is the view of BOOTICE that only shows 8mb]

This is the view of computer management:

[image: this is the view of computer management]

This is the view of diskpart:

[image: this is the view of diskpart]

+: by the way i tested this in windows 10 1703 (“Creators Update”) and shows me same!

Comment: Until  Windows 10 Version 1703, Windows supported only one partition on a removable drive (the first primary partition).  If you're sticking with  Win 7 and want to access the entire drive, you will need to create a single partition for the whole drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Access to all of the partitions of USB in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/858811/get-access-to-all-of-the-partitions-of-usb-in-windows)

Comment: @fixer1234 thanks i tested it before but i get same result as win 7 shows me. my problem is there's no more partition for migrate to this 8mb to back 32gb original capacity

Comment: Just start from scratch.  Delete that tiny partition and allocate the entire drive to a single new partition.  If you are going to upgrade to Win 10, you can create more than one partition after wiping the drive.  BTW, it's possible that the drive has failed.

Comment: @fixer1234 ok i deleted it and now there is single 8mb allocate partition. it's now healthy (primary partition)

Comment: @fixer1234 how can i know driver failed? and is there any way to bring back to normal?

Comment: If the drive previously had an 8 MB partition and the rest was unallocated space that wasn't visible, and you deleted the partition, you should see 32 GB of unallocated space.  If you aren't seeing that, it sounds like the drive has failed.

Comment: Your symptoms are a little different from what's described in the following post, but there are variations in symptoms when the drive fails, and they all pretty much come down to the same thing.  Take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only; I suspect yours has the same problem.

Comment: @fixer1234 yes it doesnt show rest partition so unfortunately my drive is failed. Thanks i will look for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I Can finely fix the problem. thanks to @fixer1234
ok i start research and know that my flash disk is actually fake! and after a while this might be happen and lost capacity and convert to 8mb or 32mb.
for this situation you should first of all do this steps.
**1. download ChipGenius Tool** - open the tool and then plugin the flash disk into the computer and get VID and PID - and Controller Part-Number information
**2. download http://flashboot.ru/iflash website** - and then search for flash disk by VID and PID - and looking into the list by finding Controller Part-Number by Memory chip - then know what is your chip vendor
**3. download chip vendor tool** - by searching the web you can finding your chip vendor (example for mine it was Phison and the tools name is "Phison Format and Restore tool v3.13") 
**4. open tool and click restore to reset factory flash disk chipset**

Comment: Nice work. So how did you determine that it was a fake? Step #4 showed that the entire capacity was 8 MB?

Comment: @fixer1234 actually i just realized the only way to recognize this type of flash disk is the problem they get!! the 8mb or 32mb capacity is one of the most common problem they actually deal with!